# How to display Carrierwave cached thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use Carrierwave to allow users to attach images to their posts.  In the list of posts I display the thumbnails (in haml) as follows:

```
%td= image_tag post.image.url :thumb
```

If validation fails when creating a new post I display the cache like this:

```
= image_tag "/#{ImageUploader::cache_dir}/#{post.image_cache}"
```

What I can't figure out is how to display the cached thumbnail.  Checking the filesystem confirms that it lives in the same directory as the cached image.  I tried

```
= image_tag post.image_cache :thumb
```

but it errors with `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out.

1. Carrierwave does cache uploads even in cases of validation error.  That's what the cache is for, after all.  It relieves the user of the need to reupload the file.
2. Users of the gem (me, the programmer), don't need to worry about how to access the cache.  Just include the cache field in the form and attr_accessible and access the image (or whatever file) like normal.  Carrierwave will do the rest transparently.  So in my case

   ```
   %td= image_tag post.image.url :thumb
   ```

will display the image correctly, either from the store directory or the cache.

[Carrierwave on GitHub](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Comment: hi @jcm thank for this answer, it help me a lot, please there is another case to show cached image other than validation error? it work fine when an error occurs,so i want to show this cached image when i post the form and without saving record

Comment: @medBo I'm not sure what you mean.  Why wouldn't the record be saved if there was no validation error?  I think the existence of the cache is intended to be transparent to us, the programmers.  We just access the image and Carrierwave decides the rest.  Is there a particular reason why you need to access the cache directly?

Comment: reason is that i want make an image preview and when user upload his image the first time he will get a preview from cached image which means don't need saving record in this step... i discover that caching files fill tmp directory with a lot of files have you an idea how to clean up this tmp directory please?

Comment: i found this but can't understand it, my english is not well and also there is no simple example at all there : https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Delete-cache-garbage-directories

Comment: Have you posted a question for it?  You'll probably get better responses.  If you have link to it here and I'll try to answer.  It's hard to communicate in comments.  :)

Comment: yes i already posted a question about but it seems that people doesn't know answer, carrierwave doc is not efficient, you can find my question here if you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126504/cleanup-tmp-directory-with-carrierwave  thank you :)

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Nope as AFAIK Carrierwave does not cache the version if there is `validation` error

If I'm correct the Carrierwave cache the version and process it in the `after` callback hook and

validation check is performed in the `before` callback hook.

you can thing of it something like this

```
 before_callback :check_for_validation
  // do some logic
 after_callback :cache_the_version and process it
```

Any error in the before callback cause Carrierwave to bypass the latter callback chain

and hence you don't have the version cached upon stumbling validation errors. (Which I believe is expected behavior as think of it why to process and create version if they aren't **valid**)

### Error

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

This is expected behavior too because the `#{column}_cache` in your case it `image_cache` method does not take any argument

I don't think there is any way to display the cache image of a version(in your case `thumb`) considering the version is never cache upon receiving validation error

Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct in that 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)' is expected since image_cache does not take an argument.  But I have confirmed that a thumb version is indeed created in the cache directory, but there is as yet no way to access it.

Comment: @jcm your taking abt this `/#{ImageUploader::cache_dir}/#{post.image_cache}"` then this is not thumb version it `cache` of the `original `image

Comment: Yes, that is the cache of the original, but in the same directory a thumb version is also saved, at least in my setup that's what happens.

Comment: @jcm is `thumb` a version for you

Comment: Yes, I have a version called thumb.

Comment: @jcm AFAIK `version` are only created after the validation are passed  that the max I can help I can reconfirm on this mean while just paste your directory listing where the file is stored and try a give a different cached directory to the `version` :thumb and see if the image is getting saved over there